# How to determine, a priori, whether a compound has multireference character?

Tags: correlation-energy, electronic-structure

We say a system has *multireference character* if it is not well described at the SCF level by a single configuration/Slater determinant. Not accounting for this can lead to errors in post-SCF methods, which often rely on expansions of additional configurations generated from the SCF solution. It is fairly easy that this sort of error has occurred once a post-SCF solution has been constructed, but are there ways to predict this without performing a high level calculation?

I would be interested in both heuristic methods (*e.g.* compounds containing atom X or structure Y tend to have issues) as well as more quantitative approaches (*e.g.* X property from a DFT calculation is a good diagnostic for multireference character).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not going to be a full answer, but maybe a starting point, a pointer to somewhat troubled systems. The general keyword here is **degeneracy**. Whenever you have fewer electrons than fit in the degenerate orbitals, two things may happen: In the simple case the molecule will distort, see aromaticity and anti-aromaticity. In the complicated case, you guessed it, you'll have a multireference system. A popular example for this is the rotational barrier of ethene, where you have degenerate, but orthogonal orbitals at the 90° dihedral. Two electrons, two orbitals, forced singlet will lead to no solution. If you treat it with TCSCF (two-configuration SCF) you'll get a qualitative solution, similar for CAS[2,2], and even UHF.

So the short and very unsatisfactory answer is, whenever you see a high symmetry, you should be careful.

Another obvious point is: anything with transition metals. Partially unoccupied d-orbitals will almost always need multi-reference treatment. In other words: [Transition-metal chemistry is a graveyard for MP2 (large pdf via the Internet Archive))](https://web.archive.org/web/20150909233705/http://esqc.ups-tlse.fr/11/lectures/ESQC-Neese-1-1x2.pdf), dito in [Koch/Holthausen's DFT book](https://books.google.de/books?id=qm5cCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT220&lpg=PT220&dq=Transition-metal+chemistry+is+a+graveyard+for+MP2).

#### Some practical approaches:

1. Calculate the fractional occupation number weighted electron density (FOD). This is fast and can be done at the semi-empirical level.<sup>[1]</sup> I don't think there is a faster (practical) way of doing this. (*I cannot believe I forgot about this before.*)
2. A more conventional approach: UHF for an initial guess will give you approximate natural orbitals. You can use this to determine an active space, if you are so inclined.<sup>[2]</sup>
3. UDFA and stability checks. Most Density Functional Methods are surprisingly robust about multi-reference character. If you run a calculation, then perform a stability analysis, which runs into a broken symmetry solution, you'll need to do multi-reference wave function methods.
   In general, performing a cheap method, will likely give you a HOMO-LUMO gap. When even your program of choice warns you about it being small, you might want to check for MR character.<sup>[3]</sup>

Obviously, your mileage may vary, and you need to check what is feasible for your system.

---

1. Resources:

   - Original Paper: Grimme, S.; Hansen, A. A Practicable Real-Space Measure and Visualization of Static Electron-Correlation Effects. *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **2015,** *54* (42), 12308–12313. [DOI: 10.1002/anie.201501887](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201501887).
   - Please see on Chemistry.se: [Is there a reliable way to determine if a chemical system is more suited to be calculated using a multireference method instead of DFT?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/89470/4945)
   - Orca input library on FOD: [FOD analysis](https://sites.google.com/site/orcainputlibrary/orbital-and-density-analysis/fod-analysis)
   - xtb manual: [Fractional Occupation Density Calculation](https://xtb-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/properties.html#fractional-occupation-density-fod-calculation), also see the repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/grimme-lab/xtb)
2. See Chemistry.se for some more details: [Is it reasonable to use natural orbitals of an unrestricted HF calculation as a basis to start a CASSCF calculation for a radical](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/69929/4945)
3. Some related questions on Chemistry.se (I know this gets old, but that's where the resources are.):

   - [U- or RO-method for Singlet-Triplet Gap?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/49174/4945)
   - [Calculating singlet-triplet gap and open-shell singlet character](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/55736/4945)
   - this is also a bit related: [Similarities and Differences between Resonance and MCSCF treatments](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/34215/4945)[*Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **2015,** *54* (42), 12308–12313](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201501887)

Answer (score 15):

As Martin has said a practical way to decide if a molecule requires multi-reference treatment is to calculate the unrestricted Hartree Fock natural orbitals.<sup>[1]</sup> Significant fractional occupancy of a UHF natural orbital indicates that the orbital should be included in the active space.

For a nonorthogonal finite basis set, they are given as

$$\mathbf{S}(\mathbf{D_\alpha+\mathbf{D_\beta}})\mathbf{S}\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{S}\mathbf{C}\mathbf{n},$$

where $\mathbf{S}$ is the overlap matrix, $\mathbf{D}_\alpha$ and $\mathbf{D}_\beta$ are the reduced first order density matrices for the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ spins, respectively, the columns of $\mathbf{C}$ contain the coefficients of the natural orbitals, and the diagonal matrix $\mathbf{n}$ holds the occupation numbers.

Specifically wavefunction with significant fractional occupancy (roughly between 0.02 and 1.98) should constitute the active space for static (non-dynamical) correlation.

For example, this can be performed in Molpro as

```
***, HF
symmetry,nosym 
memory,400,m
orient,noorient

basis=6-31G**

geometry = {
N 0 0 0
O 0 0 1.75
}

{UHF;save,2101.2}
{matrop
load,D,Den
load,S
natorb,Cnat,D
mult,SC,S,Cnat
tran,D_nat,D,SC  ! = SC' D SC
prid,D_nat
save,Cnat,2150.2
}
{put,molden,orbitals.gmolden;orbital,2101.2}
{put,molden,check.gmolden;orbital,2150.2}
```

Molden will automatically print the occupations in the orbital dump (2101.2) but the `matrop` can be also used to solve the eigenvalue problem manually

The result for example here is

```
   1.99999995   1.99999988   1.99987846   1.99937413   1.99796035   1.96525179   1.96022720   1.00000000   0.03977280   0.03474821   0.00203965   0.00062587   0.00012154   0.00000012   0.00000005   0.00000000  -0.00000000  -0.00000000  -0.00000000  -0.00000000  -0.00000000  -0.00000000  -0.00000000  -0.00000000  -0.00000000  -0.00000000   0.00000000   0.00000000
```

Which is in agreement with reference [1].

(If you do plan to do multi-reference however, do never use Hartree-Fock orbitals. **They are the worst!** Use DFT orbitals as a starting place.)

### References:

1. Pulay, P.; Hamilton, T. P. UHF natural orbitals for defining and starting MC‐SCF calculations. *J. Chem. Phys.* **1988,** *88* (8), 4926–4933. [DOI: 10.1063/1.454704](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.454704).